# Linking script.js to html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to link the script.js file to html so that I can add some interactive attributes to the page. In the example below, the purpose was to change the door1 image when it's clicked on. It doesn't work for some reason, if anyone can give some feedback, that'd be very helpful!

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chore Door!</title>
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class='door-row'>
<img id='door1' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg'>

 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js">
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the script.js code:

```
var doorImage1 = document.getElementById('door1');
var botDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/robot.svg"
doorImage1.onclick = () => {doorImage1.src=botDoorPath}
```

Comment: change test/javascript to text/javascript and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo. `<script type="test/javascript" src="./script.js">` should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js">`.
Here is your HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chore Door!</title>
<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class='door-row'>
<img id='door1' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg'>

 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js">
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've changed it to "text/javascript" but still no luck.

Comment: It still does not change the image when I clicked.

Comment: Try changing `./script.js` to `script.js` and `./style.css` to `style.css`

Comment: That was my second thought. I asked in my answer, but you got to it first haha

Answer (score 4):

First off: You have `test/javascript` instead of `text/javascript` under type. :)

***EDIT*** for the answer:

changing `./script.js` to `script.js` works for sibling files that are in the same folder.

using `../` goes up a level, and `/` uses root file path. Glad you're sorted!

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I changed it but still nothing is happening.

Comment: Where is the script located relative to the HTML file?

Comment: It worked when I changed ./script.js to script.js. Thanks!

Comment: I was gonna say. It's relative, so if it's a sibling, you just specify the file. You can use `../` to go up a level, or just use `/` to specify root file path. Glad you got it sorte3d! Can you mark answered? So it'll help somebody in the future?